# PHP/MySQL won't INSERT and echo as it should?

Tags: php, mysql, validation

What the following script does (or should do):

- Connects to DB
- Includes a function for creating a 5 digit code
- User enters their email address
- Checks if it's a valid email
- Inserts the email into the 'email' column
- Checks if email already exists, if so, let the user know and break script
- Runs the function for creating a 5 digit code
- Checks the 'unique_code' column if it already exists, if so, loop from 5 digit code creation function
- If all is valid, hide the form and display the (ajax from a separate JS) thank you div
- Display the unique code to the user

Everything runs, however the unique_code is not inserted into the DB and is not displayed when it does "Thank you! ".

What am I doing wrong and what needs to be modified?

Thank you!

**Code**

```
    <?php

    require "includes/connect.php";

    function generateCode($length = 5) {

    $characters = 'bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';

    $string = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $string .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }

    return $string;

}


$msg = '';

if($_POST['email']){

    // Requested with AJAX:
    $ajax = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']  == 'XMLHttpRequest');

    try{
        //validate email
        if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Invalid Email!');
        }

        //insert email
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails
                        SET email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");

        //if already exists in email column
        if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){
            throw new Exception('You are already on the notification list.');
        }

        if($ajax){
            die('{"status":1}');
        }

        //start creating unique 5 digit code
        $unique_code = "";
        $inserted = false;

        // Keep looping until we've inserted a record
        while(!$inserted) {

        // Generate a code
        $unique_code = generateCode();

        // Check if it exists
        if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT unique_code FROM coming_soon_emails WHERE unique_code = '$unique_code'")) {

        // Check no record exists
        if ($result->num_rows == 0) {

            // Create new record
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails (email,unique_code) VALUES ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "','$unique_code')");

            // Set inserted to true to ext loop
            $inserted = true;

            // Close the result object
            $result->close();

        }
        } else {

        // Quit if we can't check the database
        die('Something went wrong with select');
    }   
}

    }

    catch (Exception $e){

        if($ajax){
            die(json_encode(array('error'=>$e->getMessage())));
        }

        $msg = $e->getMessage();        
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>example</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <form id="form" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $msg?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
    </form>

    <div id="thankyou">
    Thank you! <?php echo $unique_code;?></p>
    </div>


</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this snippet part of a class? or are you trying to use __private__ outside of a class?

Comment: @Mark Baker: That is my complete code for my index.php. Example of using it within a class?

Comment: @Mark Baker: Updated code without use of private, not functioning as it should.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using the `private` keyword outside a class definition, which isn't allowed.

Comment: @Pekka: You are right! I have tested it and got the same error message.

Comment: @Pekka: Outside of a class? Example please. Thank you

Comment: @jeremycollins I'm having a hard time thinking up an example :) `private` is for class methods only (see [visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) in the PHP manual on OOP). You don't seem to be using it in a class context. What are you using it for? (**Edit**: If you want an example for use within a class: `class classname { private $varname; }`

Comment: @Pekka: I asked someone for assistance and they gave me the function using private. If I remove private from the function, everything works, aside from inserting the unique_code into the db and then displaying it to the user on screen in the "thankyou" div. I have no idea why..

Comment: @Pekka: I have updated the code - it just doesn't want to INSERT the unique_code into the db and then display it to the user :/

Comment: @jeremy are you sure that the unique_code function actually returns a code?

Comment: @Pekka: Hmm it should be returning $string which should be a length of 5. Maybe I'm missing something.. it's almost 4am so a little tired trying to figure this out :)

Comment: @jeremy try echoing it out straight after the call, to see whether anything is in it.

Comment: @Pekka: It's empty. But shouldn't $unique_code = generateCode(); say for $unique_code to equal the returned $string var?

Comment: @jeremy it should indeed, and I can't see anything wrong with the function. Really strange

Comment: @Pekka: me neither :( just won't echo the created string!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a primary key on 'email' in the coming_soon_emails table?  Since you've already inserted one entry for the given email address, that would keep you from inserting a second entry with the unique value.

Why not do an UPDATE instead of an INSERT once you have determined the unique key?

Comment: 'email' is primary :) what would I have to remove, modify, etc?

Comment: I would suggest changing the 2nd INSERT to something like:  UPDATE coming_soon_emails SET unique_code = "$unique_code" WHERE email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])